# Show $\lim_n(x_{n+1} - x_n) = 0$ if $<x_n>$ satisfies $2x_n \le x_{n-1} + x_{n+1}$ for all $n \in \mathbb N$

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis

Let $<x_n>$ be a bounded real number sequence. Show $\lim_n(x_{n+1} - x_n) = 0$ if $<x_n>$ satisfies $2x_n \le x_{n-1} + x_{n+1}$ for all $n \in \mathbb N$.

My try : Let $a_n = x_{n+1} - x_n$. The given condition is same as $x_n - x_{n-1} \le x_{n+1} - x_n$. Therefore, $<a_n>$ is monotonic, bounded, and convergent. If we can show $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n = 0$, then $lim_n(x_{n+1} - x_n) = 0$.

Now I'm stuck in how to show $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n = 0$. Is my approach right? If so, please give me an hint.

Comment: This seems like a good start, but have you used that the sequences is bounded?

Comment: @MichaelBurr Was not the boundedness of $x_n$ used to conclude that $a_n$ is bounded?

Comment: I think you should make use of telescoping sums.

Comment: By the way, it is enough to show $\sum_n a_n < \infty$ to conclude $a_n \to 0$; one does not need to know the value of the sum.

Comment: @LoveTooNap29 One approach is to use the boundedness again.

Comment: Consider the sequence $x_n=n$.  Then, the sequence satisfies the given constraint because $2n\leq (n-1)+(n+1)=2n$.  However, the differences do not go to zero (as they are all $1$), so at least one more fact must be brought in to what you've done above.

Comment: @mickep I know that, I'm pointing out that what the OP has done is not enough to finish the problem because $x_n=n$ satisfies all the conditions that the OP derives about $a_n$, but doesn't complete the problem.  I'm trying to point out that the OP should bring boundedness in one more time to finish the argument.

Comment: @MichaelBurr Nice example. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hints:

- You have a good start to observe that $x_n-x_{n-1}\leq x_{n+1}-x_n$.
- Suppose that for some $m$, $x_m-x_{m-1}=\varepsilon>0$.  Then, for all $n\geq m$, $x_n-x_{n-1}\geq\varepsilon>0$.  This implies that $x_n\geq x_{m-1}+(n-m+1)\varepsilon$.  This gives that $x_n$ is unbounded, a contradiction.
- Therefore, $x_n$ is a decreasing sequence.  Since bounded decreasing sequences are convergent, $x_n$ is a convergent sequence.  But the the pairwise differences in convergent sequences go to zero.

Comment: Thanks for detailed hint. You proved that $<x_n>$ is decreasing, bounded sequence. Therefore, $<x_n>$ is convergent, and it is cauchy sequence. As $<x_n>$ is a cauchy sequence, $lim_n(x_{n+1} - x_n) = 0$. Do I understand right?

Comment: Yes, that's right (although one doesn't need to go all the way to Cauchy, it works).

Comment: Oh, I see. Thanks for your hint again.